# Inline term reference field for each checkbox of node reference field

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a content type with a node reference field biblio attached to it for this which can have multiple values selected. Now I want to attach a vocabulary (term reference) named languages attached to each selected value of the node reference field. I need a solution that will make it easier to manage the database side as well as the widget for the field.![enter image description here][1]

On the left we have list of nodes with their IDs and check box to select each node. What I want to do is, add check boxes to select one or more languages to be attached to the selected node. For this I created a vocabulary named languages but there does not seem to be a direct way to do this using references or entity reference or any of the available modules.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit deeper what you are trying to do? Seems like you are building a library site

Answer (score 0):

One way would be adding language field to vocabulary it self.

But if you want to allow admin to select term and language while editing nodes in your content type use field collections:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1V1ofpgUw-Y

https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection

Comment: I tried this using field collection but it does not allow adding a term reference field for every option in the node reference field.